# Validating Facebook login on the server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

A web application supports log in via Facebook using the JavaScript SDK.

The Facebook authentication happens client side. Once successful, FB.getLoginStatus() is called and the authentication token and userID are sent to the server.

The web application stores the Facebook userID in its database.

How does the server know that the user has logged in successfully and that the authentication token and userID have not been faked client side? Is there a way of doing this validation server-side without sending a request to Facebook's server?

Comment: No, you will have to make a call to FB’s servers to validate the access token.

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while since I last did this - I seem to recall there is something that can be done with a shared key and OAuth to check that the authentication token is valid.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug

Comment: ah ok so a long term access token can be generated but this needs to be done server to server

Comment: I think there's a way to do it using the authResponse.signedRequest parameter that is returned from e.g. FB.getLoginStatus. There is some Java code here that seems to do it: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-implement-facebook-oauth-2.0-app-authorization-process-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above, you can do this by forwarding the authResponse.signedRequest parameter to the server and decode/check it on the server without having to send a server side request to Facebook's server.

Comment: I don't understand - if you validate it client-side how does the server know it is valid when it receives it?

Comment: this was a while ago so may be wrong, but from memory:
 - the login happens in the browser by sending a request to Facebook's server
 - Facebook's server returns authResponse.signedRequest that can't be unencrypted by the browser
 - you can forward authResponse.signedRequest from the browser to your server, your server can unencrypt it to check it's valid and has been signed by Facebook